# Vim Regex to remove character (:) if not followed by a character and the end of the string

Tags: regex, vim

I'm trying to use Vim regex to remove the `:` character if it is not followed by `’` and the end of the string (`$`).

```
wi:ti:h > witih # : is removed
ashe:’ # : is not removed
ho:yija:he:’ > hoyijahe:’
```

Doing some research below is what I've been trying but can't get it to work.

```
%v/:\’$\@! //g
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this substitution:

```
%s/:\('$\)\@!//g
```

Comment: can you explain this notation?

Comment: `\@!` is negative lookahead assertion in `vim`. It matches `:` when it is not followed by single quote at the end of line.